# How to reset specific layer weights for transfer learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am looking for a way to re initialize layer's weights in an existing keras pre trained model.

I am using python with keras and need to use transfer learning, 
I use the following code to load the pre trained keras models

```python
from keras.applications import vgg16, inception_v3, resnet50, mobilenet
vgg_model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
```

I read that when using a dataset that is very different than the original dataset it might be beneficial to create new layers over the lower level features that we have in the trained net.

I found how to allow [fine tuning](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/) of parameters and now I am looking for a way to reset a selected layer for it to re train. I know I can create a new model and use layer n-1 as input and add layer n to it, but I am looking for a way to reset the parameters in an existing layer in an existing model.

Comment: I suggest you to not reset the weights, especially for the first few layers as they encode generic features. Instead, let the fine-tuning process change them. Just use a very small learning rate.

Comment: I read that fine tuning works better in cases the datasets are of a close distributions where using the lower level features works better when the data is far for the training set, this is a more elegant substitute for taking layer n-x and feeding it to a new model with new layers and letting them learn for themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason you may want to re-initalize the weights of a single layer `k`, here is a general way to do it:

```python
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras import backend as K

vgg_model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
sess = K.get_session()

initial_weights = vgg_model.get_weights()

from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform  # Or your initializer of choice

k = 30 # say for layer 30
new_weights = [glorot_uniform()(initial_weights[i].shape).eval(session=sess) if i==k else initial_weights[i] for i in range(len(initial_weights))]

vgg_model.set_weights(new_weights)
```

You can easily verify that `initial_weights[k]==new_weights[k]` returns an array of `False`, while `initial_weights[i]==new_weights[i]` for any other `i` returns an array of `True`.

Comment: thanks, no way to just use a simple command like model.get_layer(n).reset_weights(<initializer>)?

Comment: @thebeancounter is the proposed solution *that* complicated?

Comment: It is a possible solution, intuitively there should be a simpler one. I accepted it because it is a valid solution and it deserves the proper credit.